# How to force a TextView to wrap words

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I'm having a bit of a problem. This is how my app looks:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wAN1.jpg

As you can see everything seems nice except the last editText and textView. I know that I can use stretch and shrink columns, but I don't want that because its going make some columns very compressed in comparison to others. I decided that I want to compress the textViews into 2 lines. So the question is: How do i force the TextViews to wrap to another line if there is more than 1 word? For example Black Steel, Bismuth Bronze and Sterling Silver should take 2 lines because there are 2 words. And the Steel(thats cut out on the picure) should take one line.

Comment: post the xml code not just the image.

Comment: Instead of a single TextView for Black Steel etc, could you use a vertical linear layout with two TextView in it (one for "Black", one for "Steel")?

Comment: I got it to work by setting EMS to some random small value. But still, is there a way to do that? @henry000 that seems like a hack, I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the newline "\n" escape character

Comment: Wow, if this works that's the simplest and coolest solution ever.

Answer (score 0):

or you can truncate the text using android:ellipsize and android:singleLine attribute on your TextView declaration.

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
```